# Relative node mobility Omnet++

Tags: omnet++, inet

My network consists of two aodv host nodes.. one node's mobility is CircleMobility and the other's mobility is LinearMobility. My purpose is to move the node with CircleMobility relative to the position of node with LinearMobility. But the node with CircleMobility takes the initial position as reference and continues to circle the path while the other node gets out of its range.

is there any framework that i should add to Omnet++.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any mobility model that has this specific behavior. In general, if you want custom mobility, then you should write your own mobility model. Refer to [the documentation](https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/neddoc/index.html?p=inet.mobility.base.MovingMobilityBase.html) of the super class of `CricleMobility` for more information and a list of sub classes.